# Is there a library to get a calendar in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-package

hope you all are having a great day.
I need an interactive calendar like this in one of my apps

[image: calendar image]

I was wondering if there's a library in react that can help me achieve this

Comment: search for https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-big-calendar`
This is similar to your calendar. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar.
There are some demo available for calendar.you can check.
http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/